# How to Handle Touch Event Uniformly Across Multiple Screen Size?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am currently working on an App which will have 2 parts: Test Builder to drag-and-drop like Photoshop to build the test and Test Simulator for player to play.

The thing is there needs to be touch events, like whenever user taps a specific area like 50x50dp or px, some action needs to take place.

However, due to multiple screen sizes of Android phones, how do I ensure that the user taps shall be at same location and uniform all across the board?

Thanks in Advance,
Rohit Kumar

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Already checked that link out before posting the question! Not useful in this situation because I need a way so that I can get and set user tap location uniformly across multiple screen sizes.

Comment: How will you be mapping out the available space? won't you use clicklisteners for each area? If your views are organised in constraint layout they will automatically resize to fit any screen but will preserve their relative position to one another.